# VS2015 Convert javascript to typescript and node modules

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I developed a javascript web app with npm and webpack. Now I converted all those .js files to .ts by using the powershell command stated [here](https://gist.github.com/staxmanade/6414463/20216c7ab3931c6c967ef146f4c0598d95d0331f). The succeeding actions in the link is using grunt; I want to directly use VS2015 Typescript project but I cannot find any reference on the net about what to do with the node_modules and how I can fully convert all my package.json and webpack into Typescript project. The Task Runner Explorer in VS2015 only supports Grunt and Gulp tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend going with the "bare-foot" solution first. I'd rely much less on VS2015. It's maybe the best IDE available, but JS and TS projects can be handled from command line without relying on the magic of the IDE. This way you can gain a deeper understanding of these technologies and I think now it would be easier too.

I recommend the following steps:

- create a tsconfig.json in the root folder. Read around, there's plenty of info available. Just one hint: use 'filesGlob' to specify the files to compile.
- use TSD to get the .d.ts files of the libs you use from DefinitelyTyped. You might create, or at least just declare, the missing packages.
- run 'tsc  --project .' from command line to compile everything. You'll see the errors that are to be solved.

I'm typing from mobile, I can edit the codes tomorrow. Have any comments?

Comment: hey, thank you for your info. yeah i switched back to atom because I found out that VS has no tsconfig.json support yet. Without that config I need to put a "///reference" to all my files which is quite many. I'm having problems fixing all errors as there is no automated way to scan and auto fix js to ts errors (Resharper doesn't have all). I was also stuck at how to use one npm package as it does not have a .d.ts file. Maybe I'll resume js to ts conversion some other time.

Comment: Seems like to be hell of a job... 2 more things that might be useful. You can write your own definitions for external libs, I've done it a few times if it was not on DefinitelyTyped. The other is that you can start migrating your project one file at a time. In a huge project I did rewrite a few core modules in TS while the rest remained in JS.